# Highcharts not showing tooltip after update from null

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a small graph where I use two series. The first Data consists of 2 series with 5 elements where the last 3 values are null. I added a shared tooltip and I can see that the tooltip is displayed correctly (`testtest`). When I switch to the second Data (2 series with 5 elements and no null values), I only see the right tooltip (`testtest`) on the first 2 elements and not on the other 3.

live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastienpattyn/bjkdms8w/13/

Some solutions on stackOverflow said to change the data elements to `{y: 1}` . but that is not fixing the issue. Any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Issue created on Highcharts github repo https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt at an odd workaround is setting the tooltip formatter in the initial options, and then using `setData` with `updatePoints` set to `false` (4th parameter). This does seem to provide the desired functionality.

For example ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z456ckbh/)):

```
let chart1 = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
    series: [{
        data:[], 
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return  this.y+'<br/> serie 1';
            }
        }
    },{ 
        data: [],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return  this.y+'<br/> serie2';
            }}
    }], 
    tooltip: {
        shared:true
    }
});


function firstData() {
    let series1 = [8, 4, null, null, null];
    let series2 = [2, 7, null, null, null];
    updateChart(series1, series2);
}

function secondData() {
    let series1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
    let series2 = [9,8,7,6,1];
    updateChart(series1, series2);
}

function updateChart(series1, series2) {
    // false last parameter here fixes it
    chart1.series[0].setData(series1, true, null, false);
    chart1.series[1].setData(series2, true, null, false);
}
```

Note that it is probably wiser to wait for the official fix in version 7.1.3.

Comment: This is indeed working for my example, but In the case that I want to dynamically change the amount of series, without knowing it might be hard to predefine it at the top. This workaround can do it for now, but I'll wait for the next release, any idea when this will be?

Comment: @SebastienPattyn I don't know, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Nice workaround is to use the `formatter` feature

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return  this.y+'<br/> test';
}
```

check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/srq61um2/

Here is more information about [formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) option

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I updated my fiddle because it was not an exact replication of my issue. The problem is that each serie must have a different tooltip, with different message, https://jsfiddle.net/sebastienpattyn/bjkdms8w/13/

Comment: It looks like the tooltip gets stuck with the first data.lenght of the first series.
If you click on the "2nd Data" button first, the issue will not appear.

Comment: I noticed, the problem is that we are loading the data from an api, based on the current week, Since we don't have any data for the coming days, it will allways be null first

Comment: You did well to report the case, it looks like a bug :)
It will be probably fixed in v7.1.3